# Haskell List Syntax with :

Tags: haskell

Haskell; `x`,`y`: integers.

```
x : [y] : []
```

What happens in this case? Is `[y]` added to `[]` or is `x` added to `[y]` first? Is the result `[x,[y]]` or `[[x,y]]`?

I'm sorry for my bad English and thank you for your help.

Comment: in `[[x,y]]` both `x` and `y` must have the same type -- in Haskell, all elements of a list must have the same type. But in `[x,[y]]`, `x` must be of the same type as `[y]`, i.e. a list, with elements of the same type as that of `y`.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask ghci about fixity information:

```
> :i :
data [] a = ... | a : [a]   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
infixr 5 :
```

Ignoring the first line for a moment, the second line says `infixr 5`, which means that `:` associates to the right and has precedence 5. "Associates to the right" means the operator groups "towards the right", so `e1 : e2 : e3` means `e1 : (e2 : e3)`.

Other options include `infixl` (grouping "toward the left") and `infix` (if grouping would be needed, report an error). For example, `e1 + e2 + e3` means `(e1 + e2) + e3` because `+` is `infixl`:

```
> :i +
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  ...
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
infixl 6 +
```

And `True == True == True` is a parse error because `==` is `infix`:

```
> :i ==
class Eq a where
  (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
  ...
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
infix 4 ==
```

When there are multiple operators, the precedence is used to tell how they are grouped, but your expression involves only one operator, namely, `(:)`, so the precedence is not needed to decide what your expression means.

Of course, you can always use explicit parentheses to disambiguate or to group operators "the other way"; e.g. `(e1 : e2) : e3` is also a valid expression and means something different from `e1 : (e2 : e3)`, and `(True == True) == True` is valid and evaluates to `True` even though `True == True == True` is not valid.

Here are some examples showing the difference:

```
> 1 : 2 : [3,4]
[1,2,3,4]
> 1 : (2 : [3,4])
[1,2,3,4]
> (1 : [2]) : [[3,4],[5]]
[[1,2],[3,4],[5]]
```

Or, even more to the point:

```
> let e1 = []; e2 = ["ab","cd"]; e3 = [["ef","gh"],["ij"]]
> e1 : e2 : e3
[[],["ab","cd"],["ef","gh"],["ij"]]
> e1 : (e2 : e3)
[[],["ab","cd"],["ef","gh"],["ij"]]
> (e1 : e2) : e3
[["","ab","cd"],["ef","gh"],["ij"]]
```

(Cooking up values that make both of these expressions well-typed was fun!)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the type

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

In words: `(:)` takes an `a` and a list of `a`s and makes it a list of `a`s.

Thereby, in `x : [y] : []`, the second part `[y] : []` is a list of lists with items of the same type as `y`. Thereby  `x` must be a list of items that have the same type as `y`. E.g.

```
y = 1
x = [2,3]
list = x:[y]:[]
```

and `list` is `[[2,3],[1]]`.

Edit: Overread that `x` and `y` should be integers. That of course would not work, see the explanation and try it in ghci.

Comment: If you type `:i (:)` in ghci you can find out, that the fixity of `:` is infixr. Thus, if as supposed by the OP, `x` and `y` are integers then the expression x : [y] : [] is not well typed ... If you, however evaluated (x : [y]) : [] the result would be [[x,y]].

Comment: The type cannot be used to answer OP's question, which is about fixity and parsing rules.